# Using perl within Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, perl, ios, cpan

CPAN has a ton of very useful libraries. Outside of porting them to Objective-C, is there is method to embed perl code in Objective-C on iOS? I am particularly interested in using [Spreadsheet::Read](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Spreadsheet-Read/Spreadsheet/Read.html) to read Excel file data (and no, I don't want to force users to re-save their files as CSV).

Comment: What libraries do you want to use? There might be native code that does what you need already.

Comment: I'm interested in reading Excel spreadsheets without forcing users to re-save them as CSV files. The CPAN library Spreadsheet::Read seems like one possibility since I can't find any publicly available Excel-format parsing libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read [perldoc perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html), which documents how to embed perl in a C program?

Answer (score 1):

Run the perl script with NSTask().

Comment: This is a good idea, but if perl is not installed on the system (I am coding for iOS) I presume this isn't possible...

Comment: Also, do your best to avoid `system()` calls. Use `NSTask` instead. `system()` is unsafe, and not recommended.

Comment: Both `NSTask` and `system()` are unavailable on iOS.

Comment: You did not specify that you were using iOS.  I recommend you update your question to include that you are using iOS.

Comment: Thanks Itai, I thought in the back of my head that something was safer than system(), but I forgot the name.