# Using Perl code in iOS/ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, perl, sample

How can I incorporate perl code into an native iOS/Objective application? Could you provide a sample?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using perl within Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533289/using-perl-within-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

The basics of calling Perl code from C is described in the [perldoc perlembed](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed.html).  It's pretty straightforward to link a C program to the Perl interpreter and give it code to execute.  However, I haven't been able to find an iOS build of Perl, which may mean you have to build it yourself.

Unfortunately, I don't have access to an iOS development environment so I can't give you any actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to jailbreak your device to install perl:

```
http://blog.thireus.com/how-to-install-ios-perl-framework-on-iphone-ipod-touch-or-ipad
```

You'll still need to follow the perl embedding guide (as Chris Reuter) said.