# Is it possible to run perl on iOS in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, perl

Is it possible to run a perl script in Xcode specifically iOS? If so, how?

Comment: Why do you need to do that in the first place?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533289/using-perl-within-objective-c

Comment: @Alec will it work with iOS though?

Answer (score 2):

No, iOS uses Objective C. In 2010 Apple lifted that restriction to allow other languages like .NET based stuff (C#, etc), but Perl isn't bundled into the development toolkit I'm afraid.